# AVAssetWriterInput does not currently support AVVideoScalingModeFit

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I'm trying to crop a video using AVAssetWriter. I need more in-depth control over the output than the presets for AVAssetExportSession provide.  I am trying to use the output mode AVVideoScalingModeFit with my AVAssetWriterInput but this causes a crash stating:

> AVAssetWriterInput does not currently support AVVideoScalingModeFit

Here are the video settings I am using:

```
   let videoSettings: [String : Any] = [
        AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
        AVVideoWidthKey: 450,
        AVVideoHeightKey: 450,
        AVVideoScalingModeKey: AVVideoScalingModeFit,
        AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
            AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: 1000000,
            AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264Baseline41,
            AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey: false,
            AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: 23
        ]
    ]
```

My questions are two fold: 1) Why does this mode exist if I can't use it? 2) If I can use it, how am I supposed to do so?

Others have asked this question but it remains unanswered. See: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674916/avassetwriterinput-does-not-currently-support-avvideoscalingmodefit-ios-error).

Answer (score 0):

1) Just because `AVAssetWriter` doesn't support `AVVideoScalingModeKey`, doesn't mean it's not supported somewhere else in AVFoundation.

2) Scale the video frames yourself using Core Image or a `VTPixelTransferSession` or whatever is appropriate for your pipeline.